# Как с помощью CSS нарисовать бекграунд из 4-х плавно переходящих цветов?

Tags: css

[image: Пример такого изображения]
Пример такого изображения. Фон плавно переходит от желтого к голубом, как реализовать такой же переход?

Comment: Нужно использовать градиент

Comment: http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator#'\-moz\-linear\-gradient\%28left\%2C\%20rgba\%28248\%2C80\%2C50\%2C1\%29\%200\%25\%2C\%20rgba\%28241\%2C111\%2C92\%2C1\%29\%2050\%25\%2C\%20rgba\%28246\%2C41\%2C12\%2C1\%29\%2051\%25\%2C\%20rgba\%28240\%2C47\%2C23\%2C1\%29\%2071\%25\%2C\%20rgba\%28231\%2C56\%2C39\%2C1\%29\%20100\%25\%29\%3B'

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 3):

```
body {
background: linear-gradient(to right, #F00, #0F0, #00F, #000);
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно на скрин - там НЕ линейный градиент, если вообще градиент.

Answer (score 3):

Как то так вроде

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 500 500">


  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="myLinearGradient1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%" spreadMethod="pad">
      <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#d9c066" stop-opacity="1" />
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#6ce7f6" stop-opacity="1" />

    </linearGradient>

  </defs>

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" rx="0" ry="0" style="fill:url(#myLinearGradient1); stroke: #00500;stroke-width:;" />

</svg>
```